# Identity between resolvent and singular value density

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, singular-values

I was reading the paper

> Sengupta, Anirvan M., and Partha P. Mitra. "Distributions of singular
>   values for some random matrices." Physical Review E 60.3 (1999): 3389.

but got stuck at equation (3):

[image]

Here $\lambda_n$ are the singular values of a matrix $M$ (eventually taken to be a random matrix), $\rho(\lambda)$ denotes the density of singular values of $M$, and the  *resolvent* $\mathcal G(z)$ is defined by:

[image]

So how does (3) follow from (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have problems, but let me write what I got:

Perhaps you know that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\pi}\Im(\frac{1}{t-i\epsilon})=\delta(t)$. In any case, this follows from $\Im(\frac{1}{t-i\epsilon})=\frac{1}{\epsilon((t/\epsilon)^2+1)}$. Hence, we get the right part of (3) is equal to $2\lambda\sum_n\delta(\lambda^2-\lambda_n^2)$, so we should prove that $2t\delta(t^2-a^2)=\delta(t-a)$. Unfortunately, I prove instead that $2t\delta(t^2-a^2)=-\delta(t+|a|)+\delta(t-|a|)$.

It's easier to approximate $\delta$ by $\phi_\epsilon=\epsilon^{-1}\phi(t/\epsilon)$, where $\phi$ is compactly supported and even. Now, let $\psi$ be a test function and evaluate 
$$
\begin{align}
\int 2t\phi_\epsilon(t^2-a^2)\psi(t)\,dt &= \int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^{\infty} \\
&=-\int_{-a^2}^\infty \phi_\epsilon(s)\psi(-\sqrt{s+a^2})\,ds +\int_{-a^2}^\infty\phi_\epsilon(s)\psi(\sqrt{s+a^2})\,ds,
\end{align}
$$
where I used the change of variables $t^2-a^2=s$. Therefore, taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ we get $2t\delta(t^2-a^2) = -\delta(t+|a|)+ \delta(t-|a|)$. I don't know if I made a mistake.

Comment: I agree, $2\lambda\delta(\lambda-\lambda_n^2) = \delta(\lambda-\lambda_n) + \delta(\lambda+\lambda_n)$. But I think in this case it is safe to assume that $\lambda,\lambda_n > 0$ (singular values of random matrices are almost surely positive), in which case $\delta(\lambda+\lambda_n) = 0$. But I'm not 100% convinced by this argument.